# Putting Two Arguments into UnifDist in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Trying to compute the following expression,

```
quad(@(n)quad(@(m)unifpdf(m-n,0,1),-10,10),-10,10)
```

But I get a message saying:

```
??? Error using ==> minus
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in ==> @(m)unifpdf(m-n,0,1)
```

Can you please let me know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the following [requirement](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/quad.html):

> The function y = fun(x) should accept a vector argument x and return a vector result y, the integrand evaluated at each element of x.

`unipdf` seems to satisfy this requirement, but `quad` itself is not.

To fix this problem you need to write a wrapper function that accepts a vector argument `x`, evaluates inner integral using `quad` function, and return a vector of results:

```
function [r] = Test()
    r = quad(@(n)InnerIntegral(n),-10,10);
end

function [y] = InnerIntegral(n)
    y = zeros(size(n));
    for i = 1 : length(n)
        y(i) = quad(@(m)unifpdf(m - n(i), 0, 1), -10, 10);
    end;
end
```

Comment: So to clarify I need a wrapper function that takes the argument $n$ and spits out a vector itself?

Comment: @RedRover: Yes. I have updated my answer with an example code.